# Django: "missing 1 required positional argument: 'lookup _name'" when it is not missing?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-subquery

I am working with Django 3.1 ORM and am running (with `pytest`) a test involving a complex nested query. I get this failure:

```
self = <django.db.models.expressions.Subquery object at 0x0000027CE184D2B0>
lookup = 'lte'

    def get_lookup(self, lookup):
>       return self.output_field.get_lookup(lookup)
E       TypeError: get_lookup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lookup_name'
```

That `get_lookup(lookup)` to be called is defined (as far as I can see) in `django.db.models.query_utils.RegisterLookupMixin` as

```
def get_lookup(self, lookup_name):
    ...
```

The corresponding source statement of my test involves something like

```
value = now() - OuterRef(OuterRef('myattr2')) * timedelta(days=1)
queryset2.annotate(has_x=Exists(queryset.filter(myattr__lte=value)))
```

and there is more query construction code around it.
My debugger tells me that `self.output_field` is a `DateTimeField` object.

So overall:

- The context is an `Exists` subquery.
- The lookup is `'lte'` (as intended).
- The call provides a `DateTimeField` as `self` (from `output_field`) and `'lte'` as `lookup_name`.
- The method-to-be-called expects `self` and `lookup_name`.

The call should work, shouldn't it?
Where is the `TypeError`?

Comment: What are `myattr` and `myattr2`? I was able to reproduce similar error, the issue is that `self.output_field` is a class, not an instance as it should be, thus missing default `self` and as a result, missing `lookup_name`

Comment: Just curious, why the double `OuterRef` here? `OuterRef(OuterRef('myattr2'))`

Comment: @bdbd The inner `OuterRef` escapes the `Exists` shown in the question. The outer `OuterRef` escapes another `Exists` _not_ shown in the question that is part of the "more query construction code around it" that I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @AlexandrTatarinov is right on; that was my problem as well; `myattr` is a computed attribute created thusly:

```
annotate(myattr=Subquery(queryset3,
                         output_field=DateTimeField))
```

But for some reason, Django firmly wants a field instance for the output field, not a field class.
So `output_field=DateTimeField()` works, but my `output_field=DateTimeField` does not.
Add the parentheses and my problem is solved.

Ironically, The `output_field=` is not even required in this case! Removing it works as well as adding the parens.

To reflect on my work process, these were my mistakes:

1. I checked in the debugger that a proper `self` would be present -- but obviously not carefully enough, mistaking the `DateTimeField` class for a `DateTimeField` instance.
2. I had inserted the `output_field=DateTimeField` clause while I debugged a previous problem, but did not take it out again when it did not help. Bad idea.
3. When I wrote my question, I hesitated when I wrote *"My debugger tells me that `self.output_field` is a `DateTimeField` object."* and asked myself *"Do I know it is a `DateTimeField` object and not the `DateTimeField` class?"*, but I did not go and look in the debugger again, I only recalled that I had checked it and had been satisfied.

So my take-home lessons are:

- (from number 2): Don't do half-baked things.
- (from numbers 1&3): Trust yourself as little as possible.